# Soap Client for REST WEB Services

Tags: c++, rest, soap

I am working for a project which use REST web service in c++. I am trying to connect by using SOAP REST service to access the data. is it possible consume the REST web service without a WSDL file in SOAP. I am able to connect by using a dummy    WSDL file.